# Tumblr emedding posts: Is there a callback when iframe content is loaded?

Tags: iframe, callback, tumblr

I have an [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) layout on my homepage which either needs to know the height of its items when the page is loaded or in case of embedded content (e.g. Twitter tweets) needs to be retriggered in order to layout things correctly (otherwise the items just overlap).

For Twitter tweets I can rely on [Twitter's API](https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/events) and [use a callback](http://martinwolf.org/2015/02/02/detect-if-embedded-tweet-has-been-loaded/) when the tweet is loaded and displayed, but is there **something similar for embedding Tumblr** posts?

This is an example of embed code I am using to embed posts from Tumblr:

```
<div class="tumblr-post" data-href="https://embed.tumblr.com/embed/post/odI2x4Qr56b5o6n03UOXBQ/114053765854" data-did="c3b190b9c1feffd51293e3bcc93cefd54139ae74">
    <a href="http://afp-photo.tumblr.com/post/114053765854/china-beijing-tibetan-monks-dressed-as-demons">http://afp-photo.tumblr.com/post/114053765854/china-beijing-tibetan-monks-dressed-as-demons</a>
</div>
<script async src="http://assets.tumblr.com/post.js"></script>
```

I have scrolled through the [Tumblr API](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2), but I don't find anything relevant.

PS.: I am checking the [post.js](http://assets.tumblr.com/post.js) file to see if there is anything I could use as a hook, but no success yet.